# Xamarin.Forms Content Page title color change

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

This is the result I want to see on all my devices.

[image]

---

But it looks like this on the device with android 5.1 installed.

[image]

My third title dont see. I had to use the following definitions in my 3rd page (Yukle Page) .cs file. I am getting such a result, probably because I changed the color setting.

[image]

How can I make the title color of my 3rd page (Yukle Page) in .cs "white" in Xamarin.Forms? Thank you!

Comment: Could you please post some detailed `xaml` codes of your project?

Comment: do you have used tab page renderer?

Comment: I solved that problem with update to in Nuget, Xamarin.Forms v2.3.4.224 and solved. Thanks answers!

Answer (score 0):

You have apply theme in **Toolbar.axml** in your Android Project.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeToolbar"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Define ThemeToolbar style in **styles.xml**

```
 <style name="ThemeToolbar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

    <!-- navigation icon color -->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/accent</item>

    <!-- color of the menu overflow icon -->
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">"define your color code here"</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">"define color hex code here."</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/lightGray</item>
  </style>
```

For More info use following link:

https://blog.xamarin.com/material-design-for-your-xamarin-forms-android-apps/